# C# Adding usercontrol to usercontrol by usercontrol

Tags: c#, controls, addition

I have 3 user controls (download page, download status page, download status). I want to make when I click the download button at the download page it has to add download status to downloadstatuspage. I couldn't make this happen. It doesn't add.

```
//when clicked in download page
downloadstatuspage.flowlayoutpanel.Controls.Add(downloadstatus);
```

NOTE: it can add a user control to itself(user control), but it cant add to another user control.

I tried everything I see on the internet but none of them worked.

Comment: Can you add a little more of your code? There may be a problem with initialization of downloadstatuspage or downloadstatus,  also try placing a break point after the line, and see if flowlayoutpanel children actually do include downloadstatus, maybe it's added but there might be a visual problem or "mis-refrence"

Comment: downloadstatuspage only has flowlayoutpanel nothing else.
i can only add downloadstatus to mainform and downloadpage(itself)

Comment: Do it in steps and name each object :            FlowLayoutPanel newFlowLayoutPanel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
            this.Controls.Add(newFlowLayoutPanel);
            FlowLayoutPanel downloadstatus = new FlowLayoutPanel();
            newFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(downloadstatus);

Comment: i already named them, i can add dynamically to main form but i cant add to another usercontrol